# How update a platform manager version of virto commerce

Tags: virtocommerce

Is there a way to update a vc platform version from an azure setup? I can't update modules in the platform while it's version isn't the current one. I had storefront and platform installed in one web app. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please, see [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-platform/issues/1322#issuecomment-379212240)

Comment: Hello Aleksandr, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, this kind of deployment (both Platform and Storefront) on the same application, doesn't support updating platform through `Azure deployment options`.
To update platform you should repeat `4,5,6` steps from this article [deployment-to-one-azure-application](https://virtocommerce.com/docs/vc2devguide/deployment/deployment-to-one-azure-application)